# property underscore instance and getter in object-c and their equivalent in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I ran into a problem when I was trying to "translate" some Objective-C code to Swift. I define Garage and Car in CoreData. Garage has a relationship to Car called cars. I have a masterviewcontroller to display  "Garage" class and detailviewcontroller to display a NSArray of "car" class. Here is my code in Objective-C. I want to let cars = allobjects when it is nil; otherwise just return it.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* cars;

- (NSArray*) cars {
      if (_cars == nil) {
          _cars = self.garage.cars.allObjects;
       }
      return _cars;
}
```

However, in Swift, it does not have a underscore instance for property, and I cannot let cars == nil since "==" cannot be applied to operands of type [Car]. I tried to use the following code, but it gave me two errors: "attempting to access 'cars' within its own getter" and "cannot assign a value of type '[AnyObject]?' to a value of type '[Car]'"

```
var garage : Garage?
var cars : [Car] {
  if let a = cars {
  get {
   cars = self.garage?.cars.allObjects
 }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**/////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the method I used to solve my problem.

```
private var _cars: [Car]?


var cars: [Car]?
    {
    get {
        if _cars == nil {

            _cars = self.garage?.cars.allObjects as? [Car]

        }
        return _cars

    }

    set {
        _cars = cars
    }
}
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 3):

I might suggest just having a computed property:

```
var cars : [Car]? {
    return garage?.cars.allObjects    
}
```

And, remember to make `cars` variable and optional array.

Comment: This always returns the latest value of `garage?.cars.allObjects`, but the Objective-C version remembers the value once it isn't `nil` and returns that value.

Comment: I tried your code, but it gave the error "cannot convert return expression of type '[AnyObject]?' to expected return type '[Car]?' "
Thank you though

Comment: Without seeing the declarations of the `garage` and `cars` and `allObjects` properties/methods, I can't help, but I assume you'd cast it with `as? [Car]` or `as [Car]?` or something like that.

Comment: @vacawama Yes, I know. That was deliberate. In Objective-C, `NSArray` class pass-by-reference (meaning that as the original array mutated, the value returned by `cars` would change, too), but in this case, it would appear that he's using `Array` struct pass-by-value, and if you do strict translation like you did in your answer, the behavior could change.

Comment: I think I prefer my answer when the property is expensive to compute but this case is fine. +1.

Comment: @Pulsar - I agree. If you really want `copy`-style memory semantics, your answer is definitely the way to go. If you really want to reference the original array, then the computed property is the way to go. They yield very different behavior, so it just depends upon the app's needs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a lazy property:

`lazy var cars: [Car]? = self.garage?.cars.allObjects`

Comment: Seems like xcode cannot auto complete this line. When I typed: self., xcode cannot get the variable garage I define before.

Comment: @zhuangr - BTW, that can happen if you don't use `lazy` keyword. And even in that case, more than once I've found myself in situations where Xcode's code completion was confused and wouldn't work, even though it was correct. Note, this answer is not quite the same as your ObjC example (though I think it's much better than the answers that attempted an overly literal translation), because `[Car]` is pass-by-value and the ObjC `NSArray *` is a pass-by-reference. It depends upon the behavior you wanted, but I assume the computed property is what you actually intended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a [lazy var](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Your code will be (Swift 2.3):

```
lazy var cars: [Car]? = { [unowned self] in
  return self.garage?.cars.allObjects
}()
```

The trick are the *{* and the *[unowned self]*

Lazy var in sintax instance the value just one time and keep it, maybe it's what you want.

Maybe you just need a wrapper to get each time the value of *self.garage?.cars.allObjects* in which case you need a computed var, not a lazy var with a static value

```
var cars: [Car]? {
    get {
       return self.garage?.cars.allObjects
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift, you would generally replace properties with variables (var); if a property can be set in you init method and stays unchanged after that, you would use (let).

In your case, you have your own "get" method. In Swift, when you have a getter or setter method, there is no backing variable. So what you do, you create one. Typically as a private variable with a leading underscore.

You should think about how you reset the variable to nil. Having a setter is not a good idea, because you only want to allow setting the variable to nil and nothing else. If it is only set to nil inside the class itself, you can set the variable with underscore to nil. Otherwise you might add a function like "resetCars".

And note that if you have a "get" method, but none of "set", "willSet" and "didSet", you can just write the set code without any getter. So a typical usage would be:

```
private var _cars: [Car]?
func resetCars () -> Void { _cars = nil } // To allow resetting outside the class
var cars: [Car] {
    if _cars == nil {
        _cars = cleverlyCalculatedNonNilValue()
    }
    return _cars
}
```

Comment: Your solution has the same problem mine had. See the discussion under @Rob's answer.

Comment: Well, Rob's answer works in that particular case. In the general case it is rubbish, doing the calculation every time. Even if garage.cars is a dictionary, allObjects is an expensive operation. The pattern above can be used for _very_ expensive recalculations, for example if a list of data is filtered or sorted and you reset the _cars variable when the filter or sort order is changed.